# Application retrieving values at a particular time from sql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in MySQL.  The values in column named `Curr_BaL` is  updated  by different operations performing on it.  The application, which is written in Java, accesses that database.  When it runs, by default it should retrieve the last updated value.  However, I also want to be able to get the value at a specific DATE entered by the user.

I have tried to do my best, but have not successful yet, and my whole application depends on that data.

Comment: You need to _show_ what you've tried, _explain_ your **specific** problem and post any relevant code from your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not entirely clear. What I can understand is that you need a way to have your users aware of this "last updated" value.

You have several designs approach for this. I think that the simpler would be to fetch this value when you're authenticating your user, and set it to its session information, so it will be available at any time.

You can also have some kind of service caching this value (since I guess is the same for all users).

A very important thing you didn't mentioned is who updates this value, is an external application? is a process on the same application?.

Comment: first of all thanks for your suggestions 0R10N the values are updated by the user who was working on front end application which is a java application. The user wants to access the data periodically according to period which user enter.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand, users date more priority then automaticaly date. Simple way for it's using triggers. Below may be useful:

```
CREATE OR ALTER trigger on_table_ins for TABLE
active before insert position 0
AS
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.DATEFIELD IS NULL) THEN NEW.DATEFIELDD='now';
END
```

It correct for firebird, so see manual for triggers and insert current date(time) for your RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks michal for suggtions i will try it